# getting top n entries for each group, where n is different for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

imagine having this df:

```
group  time                 index  cutoff
A      2018-04-01 05:07:00  0.8    2
A      2018-04-01 05:07:00  0.7    2
A      2018-04-01 05:07:00  0.6    2
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.9    4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.87   4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.7    4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.67   4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.5    4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.47   4
```

I would want to change this df into:

```
group  time                 index  cutoff
A      2018-04-01 05:07:00  0.8    2
A      2018-04-01 05:07:00  0.7    2
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.9    4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.87   4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.7    4
B      2018-04-01 05:57:00  0.67   4
```

That means for each grouping (group, time), order by index and only select top n entries, where n is equal to the cutoff value specified in 'cutoff' for each group.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) and selecting first value `cutoff` per group by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df = df.groupby('group', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(x['cutoff'].iat[0]))
print (df)
  group                 time  index  cutoff
0     A  2018-04-01 05:07:00   0.80       2
1     A  2018-04-01 05:07:00   0.70       2
3     B  2018-04-01 05:57:00   0.90       4
4     B  2018-04-01 05:57:00   0.87       4
5     B  2018-04-01 05:57:00   0.70       4
6     B  2018-04-01 05:57:00   0.67       4
```

Comment: works like a charm - knew i needed to use apply with the head function, was not sure how to. thanks!

Comment: @jezrael can you explain what the custom function is doing here?

Comment: @SaiKumar - Sure, this is `lambda x: x.head(x['cutoff'].iat[0])` - for each group extract first value of `cutoff` and it is used for `head` function for dynamic select top rows.

Comment: @jezrael so when you do this `lambda x: x['cutoff'].iat[0]` it selects `group A=2 and group B=4` then what does the head function do here?

Comment: @SaiKumar - it select `head(2)` and then `head(4)`

Comment: @jezrael Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @jezrael, where are the 2 and 4 coming from for head()?